# Serial Com. recieving only the first 2 bytes on LPC1769

Tags: c, serial-port, lpc

Im having some issues with the serial communication on LPC1769, there is some communication in both ways between Computer(Qt developed software) and LPC1769. Communication from LPC to Computer works fine but the communication from computer to LPC doesnt works right.

I can only receive the first two bytes from the buffer sent.

```
void UART1_Init(void)
{
    PCONP |= (1<<4);    // UART1 ON

    PCLKSEL0 &= ~(0x11 << 8);
    PCLKSEL0 |= (0x1 << 8);

    U1LCR |= 1 << 7; // 0x80   line control register (DLAB=1)

    U1DLM = 0x00;       //0x001A = 26

    U1DLL = 0x1A;       //DLM. DLL . DLL 4Mhz

    U1LCR &= 0x7f;      //DLAB=0 8bits no parity

    U1FCR |= 0x01;

    SET_PINSEL(PIN_TX1,PINSEL_FUNC1);
    SET_PINSEL(PIN_RX1,PINSEL_FUNC1);

    ISER0 = 1<<6;       // interruptions UART1. 

    U1IER = 0x03;       

}

void UART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    uint32_t IIR;
    uint8_t IIRenCruso, IIRpendiente;
    uint8_t temp, lsr;

    do
    {
        IIR = U1IIR;

        IIRpendiente = IIR & 0x01;
        IIRenCruso = ( IIR >> 1 ) & 0x07;

        switch(IIRenCruso)      
        {

        case 3:
            lsr = U0LSR;    
            if ( lsr & (0x2|0x4|0x8|0x16|0x128) )
            {
                temp = U0RBR;       
                return;
            }

            case 2: //Recieve data available (RDA)
                pushRx(U1RBR);
                break;

            case 1:     //THRE Interrupt
                temp = popTx();

                if(temp != 0xff)
                    U1THR = temp;

                else{
                    f_fin_tx = 1; 
                            vaciarBuff('T');
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }   while( ! ( IIRpendiente & 0x01 ) );
}
```

Comment: Is it really your intention to have `case 3:` drop down to `case 2:` should `if ( lsr & (0x2|0x4|0x8|0x16|0x128) )` be false?   You may want to detect if case `default:` is used.

Comment: Sorry for the late. Yes it is, that case is just control (reading flags turning them to zero), nothing relevant.

Comment: Idea about drop through cases:  Add an explicit comment at the end of `case 3` stating "drop though" to prevent review confusion.

Comment: Should not `U0...` be `U1...` is 2 places?